# Numbers 5,7,9 are written on the whiteboard. In one move, we choose two numbers $a,b$ and and add a new number $5a-4b$ to the whiteboard...

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Numbers 5,7,9 are written on the whiteboard. In one move, we choose two numbers $a,b$ and and add a new number $5a-4b$ to the whiteboard. Is it possible to get the number $2021$ on the whiteboard after a set number of moves?

I honestly have no idea how to start. I've tried looking at congruencies and remainders to try and prove it's impossible but I've gotten nowhere. Hints are appreciated. :)

Comment: Hint:  Take it modulo $8$.  What remainders can we get for the numbers greater than or equal to $7$?

Comment: Are you allowed to have the same number for $a$ and $b$? (In other words, is 0 allowed?)

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be allowed @AKemats

Comment: By the way, I don't see why that'd be useful, wouldn't you just get the same number again (5a-4a=a). I might've misunderstood your question @AKemats

Comment: Also @JosephCamacho I tried that before posting this question but due to the possibility of getting negative numbers it seemed really hard to prove that we can't get the remainder $5$ for $\ge7$

Comment: Sorry - that was a brain fart lol @Cookie

Comment: Hint: Mod 8 doesn’t help. Mod 5 does.

Comment: See my comment on the answer for a simpler way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot reach 2021 through this method.

First, let's see what we get when applying this function to all pairs of numbers that we start with (letting our rows be $a$ and columns be $b$).

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & 5 & 7 & 9\\ \hline
\text{5} & 5 & -3 & -11\\ \hline
\text{7} & 15 & 7 & -1\\ \hline
\text{9} & 25 & 17 & 9 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Let's see the same table again, but with each number taken$\mod 10$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 & 5 & 7 & 9\\ \hline
\text{5} & 5 \mod 10 \equiv 5 & -3 \mod 10 \equiv 7 & -11 \mod 10\equiv 9\\ \hline
\text{7} & 15 \mod 10 \equiv 5 & 7 \mod 10 \equiv 7 & -1 \mod 10\equiv 9\\ \hline
\text{9} & 25 \mod 10 \equiv 5 & 17 \mod 10 \equiv 7 & 9\mod 10 \equiv 9 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

As you can see, for any numbers we choose, $(5a-4b)\mod 10 \equiv 5 \mod 10, 7 \mod 10,$ or $9 \mod 10$. As $2021\mod 10 \equiv 1 \mod 10$, we cannot reach it with this set of numbers.

Comment: **Simpler** $\bmod 5\!:\ 5a-4b\equiv b\,$ so the map produces no new values $\!\bmod 5,\,$ so its values remain congruent to the initial values $\equiv 0,2,4,\,$ so $\,2021\equiv 1\,$ does not occur. $\ \ $